# Partial text user search with sorting- how can I fix this?

Tags: facebook-fql

I am trying to implement a form of "public figure" search, that takes a partial string and returns both pages and users that are likely to be publicly known. On the page side I'm sorting by number of likes, on the user side I'm sorting by number of subscribers. Pages work fine. Users do not.

The crux of my problem is that I can't use CONTAINS() on the user table, like so:

```
SELECT id, name from USER where CONTAINS("Jimmy F") ORDER BY subscriber_count DESC
```

I get zero results. However, if I use the Profile table, it works. From here, I can do a sub-query, resulting in this:

```
SELECT uid,name from USER WHERE uid in (SELECT id FROM profile where
CONTAINS("Jimmy F")) ORDER BY subscriber_count DESC
```

The problem here is that the sub-query is not sorted. So, this example, I would expect to see [Jimmy Fallon](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20name,uid,subscriber_count%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20=%201646868425), who has 633k subscribers. I don't, because he isn't included in that profile subquery. I can increase the LIMIT on that subquery, but it slows it a lot (LIMIT 200 took 4 seconds to come back, and *still* didn't include Jimmy).

So my broad question here is: any ideas? I don't know where to turn for a better result, here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is due to Facebook's visibility constraints. Somewhere in the documentation, Facebook explains that when it executes any query it first gathers the results, then filters out the results that are visible.

I made some tests with this query:

```
SELECT uid, name, subscriber_count FROM user WHERE CONTAINS(_STRING_) 
  ORDER BY subscriber_count DESC
```

The more specific the value I tried, the more data I received: e.g. "Jimmy Fallon", "Paul Ryan" and "Michael Arrington" all seem to return the appropriate person as the first result. "Joe Biden" returned data, but the first 10 responses (like 'Mehmad Moha') did not include any variations of 'Joe' or 'Biden' in their name.

Other values I tried for `_STRING_` didn't return any data, including "Jimmy F", "Barack Obama", "Mitt Romney" or "Mark Zuckerberg". The results being returned must be private and not visible to me.

I'm not sure what `CONTAINS` actually searches. It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. There doesn't appear to be any correlation to whether the person returned is a friend or not.

There does seem to be the ability to add a field to it like `CONTAINS('Jimmy F', name)`, which gives an OAuth error: `'name' is not a valid search field for the user table`. I can't find any field in the user table that doesn't return this error.

You could try filing a bug report on this, but `CONTAINS()` seems to be an unsupported feature.

Comment: Yes- my issue is that CONTAINS() appears to work for partial matches on other entities (pages, for example) but isn't for the user table. I get a result if I search for "Jimmy Fallon", but not if I search for "Jimmy Fallo".

Interestingly, this carries through to the Graph API's /search method - ?type=page works, ?type=user does not. Hopefully this is not by design.